# Drupal Commerce hide cart to non authenticated users

Tags: commerce

I have a drupal 7 commerce install. I have made the views only accessible to authenticated users, but when I am not authenticated, and type in "mysite.com/cart" I still can see the cart (even though it has nothing in it).

I am using the content access module to prevent non authenticated users from viewing my produces, but I don't want anyone who is not logged in, to even know the website doubles as a store. How do I hide the cart page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix might be to write a tiny custom module that overrides the `access callback` for the cart page:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['cart']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_cart_access';
}

function MYMODULE_cart_access() {
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    return user_access('access content');
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the first thing about writing modules, could you explain further where to put the code, and any other steps that need to be done.

Comment: Check out [Telling Drupal about your module](http://drupal.org/node/1075072) and [Writing comments and implementing your first hook](http://drupal.org/node/1095546), those two pages have everything you need to know